# SQL Server: Counting Inventory Issue (with subquery)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery, reporting

I currently have a query that is going out into an inventory table (of servers), filtering which ones are 'Developer', and producing a list of distinct users from an audit-related table. Essentially, trying to find out who has access to development servers in this particular inventory.

Everything worked until I added the second line, which I commented out in the code below:

```
select  distinct tAudit.[USER_ID]
        --, count(tAudit.[USER_ID]) AS [USER_COUNT]
from table_audit as tAudit
where tAudit.inst_name IN   (
        SELECT (SUBSTRING([Computer Name],0,CHARINDEX('.',[Computer Name],0))) AS INST_NAME
        FROM table_server_inventory
        WHERE [SQL Server Edition] = 'Developer'
        )
order by tAudit.user_id asc
```

So, the question is: How can I count how many times a particular user appears? Is there a conflict with the fact I am using **distinct**? There's another query I produced, purely to see if I was on the right track. This is an example:

```
select  tAudit.[USER_ID]
        , count(tAudit.[USER_ID]) AS [USER_COUNT]
from table_audit as tAudit
where tAudit.user_id IN ('user_001', 'user_009', 'user_199', 'user_222')
group by tAudit.user_id
```

And it looked something like this:

```
USER_ID     USER_COUNT
user_001    5
user_009    32
user_199    14
user_222    8
```

Ideally, when the primary query is working it'll look like the example above, just with dozens more results.

NOTE: The table_audit is actually very large and lists servers and users each time. Example:

```
COMPUTER_NAME   USER_ID
serverAA        user_001
serverAA        user_009
serverAA        user_199
serverAA        user_222
serverBB        user_001
serverBB        user_009
serverCC        user_001
serverCC        user_199
serverCC        user_222
```

Comment: Your second query is the right way to go.  COUNT is an aggregate function and requires the GROUP BY clause that is missing in your first query.

Comment: I've tried adding the GROUP BY clause on the first query and my logic and placement must be off. I would just list all the users manually like in the second query, but there are nearly 200 of them. Plus the list is a bit dynamic -- it may change in a week.

Comment: GROUP BY goes after WHERE and before ORDER BY.  Can you post the first query with the GROUP BY that you tried?

Comment: FYI, you can think of `DISTINCT` as being just a degenerate/simplified `GROUP BY`.  it's a short-cut without all of the features.

Comment: Admitidly I'm going to refer to Gordon Linoff's answer-reply below, as he took out the DISTINCT and also referred me to include GROUP BY before ORDER BY and before WHERE. However, as I mentioned there, it's include the total amount of times a user appears in the table_audit. I am looking for that count to be for **only** the developer servers. I had one user return with access to 1804 servers, which... is more than how many developer servers there are. Oops!

Answer (score 2):

You just want a `GROUP BY` query, not `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
select tAudit.[USER_ID], count(tAudit.[USER_ID]) AS [USER_COUNT]
from table_audit as tAudit
where tAudit.inst_name IN   (
        SELECT (SUBSTRING([Computer Name],0,CHARINDEX('.',[Computer Name],0))) AS INST_NAME
        FROM table_server_inventory
        WHERE [SQL Server Edition] = 'Developer'
        )
group by tAudit.[USER_ID]
order by tAudit.user_id asc
```

Comment: This is on the right track! And your mention of GROUP BY and not using SELECT DISTINCT makes sense. However, the numbers being pulled for [USER_COUNT] are how many times that particular user appears in the table_audit total, not how many times the appear for the 'Developer' only results. How do I modify this for that specific condition?

Comment: @Erik . . . Because of the `where` clause, this should be counting only rows where the user is marked as a developer.